# Django - How to re-render a page to display data based on a form's field?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a form in which the first field is the User's ID #. What I'm trying to achieve is displaying the name on top of the field where they enter they number but I'm not sure how to do this. I was thinking about maybe somehow refreshing the page once the user tabs/clicks out of the field, but I don't know if there would be a more efficient way that could render in real time, in case the user fills out other fields before their ID# field.

Currently, I have this in my views to get the User's name based on their #, but I'm not sure how to use this in the html part, or if something else needs to be modified too

**views.py**

```
def get_e_name(request):
    e_number = request.POST.get('e_number')
    e = Saved.objects.get(a_number=e_number)
    e_name = e.saved_name
    return e_name
```

I would Like to display the e_name that get_e_name() returns on top of the first field in the form once it gets filled out

**enter_leave_area.html**

```
{% extends "operations/base.html" %}
{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" data-stations-url="{% url 'operations:ajax_load_stations' %}" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div>
            <div>
                {{ form.e_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.e_number }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.w_area.help_text }}
                {{ form.w_area }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.s_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.s_number }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
                <button type="submit" name="leave_area" value="Leave">Leave Area</button>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#id_w_area").change(function () {
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").attr("data-stations-url");
            var wAreaId = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'w_area': wAreaId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#id_s_number").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
     </script>
{% endblock main %}
```

Comment: Where is your html template

Comment: in a general sense, what you want to do here is called AJAX https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html AJAX basically means making requests to the server using javascript

Comment: @arjun added html

Comment: If you want to display the name after form fills out you need ajax.